# Smallest acceptable 16:9 video player?

Tags: video

Is there any user research or testing on the smallest size a 16:9 video could play on a website, where the user doesn't feel it's too small?

Comment: In pixels? Millimetres?

Comment: What is on the video? Talking heads? A movie? Text?

Comment: Percentage, too.

Comment: In pixels I guess as the video will be on screen. The content in them will be sports news and match highlights.

Answer (score 9):

> Where the user doesn't feel it's too small?

This is subjective and would vary by person, age-group, and screen real estate percentage. My assessment is that no one likes to see small video - unless it was in bad quality *and* watching it in large (or full screen) size would make the video visually punishing.

... OR you were watching a video and working at the same time.

The MPEG-1 Code has the smallest resolution of an NTSC video stream as: 352x240. When converted from a 4:3 aspect ratio to a 16:9 aspect ratio, it becomes **352x198**.

[image]